# Count number of nodes in binary tree in Java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

```
static int sum=0;
    public static int size(TreeNode root){
        if(root==null)
        return sum;
        sum++;
        sum=size(root.left);
        sum=size(root.right);
        return sum;
    }
```

We have to just complete the function "size" which counts the number of nodes in binary tree. I have written the above code. It is giving wrong answer for some testcases. Please explain what is wrong in above code.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
sum=size(root.left);
sum=size(root.right);
```

You are computing **two** sums, to then throw away the first one!

You could go: `return size(root.left)+size(root.right) + 1` instead.

There is **also** no point in using a **static field** `sum` here. If at all, that should be a **local** variable within that recursive method! Respectively: simply `return 0` for null, otherwise use the return I provided here. There is **no need** to for that `sum` variable in the first place!

Comment: You mean `return size(root.left)+size(root.right) + 1`

Comment: @leonardkraemer Thank you for your input! Updated the answer accordingly!

Comment: a one-liner for that mehod if be of interest to anyone `return root == null ? 0 : size(root.left) + size(root.right) + 1;`

Comment: @nullpointer Sure, but I try to not push newbies over the limit ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have not set `sum` correctly when get data from child node

```
    sum += size(root.left);
    sum += size(root.right);
```

I would advice you not use a global static variable to get the value when you want to do it recursively

```
    static int sum=0;
    public static int size(TreeNode root){
        if(root==null)
        return 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        cnt++;
        cnt += size(root.left);
        cnt += size(root.right);
        return cnt;
    }
```

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem can you give me more explanation,please?

Comment: Yeah, OK, now that you've edited it, I think it works.  It's still a bit strange in places - setting a variable to 0 then immediately incrementing it seems an odd way to set a variable to 1.  But I've removed my downvote.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks,I think the global variable makes things complicated

Comment: @ManjotsinghChug have you checked others's answer

Comment: @ManjotsinghChug This solution is correct.  Why do you think it's giving the wrong answer?  What input are you giving it, what answer are you expecting for that input, and what answer are you actually getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public static int size(final TreeNode node)
{
    if (null == node ) return 0;
    return 1 + size( node.left ) + size( node.right );
}
```